# convert json to dataframe in for loops in python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, for-loop, append

I'm trying to call the data using api and making a dataframe using for loops with returned json. I am able to create the first dataframe but my for loop only returns the first json -> dataframe. After a few days struggle, I decided to ask guidance from experts here..

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

# create an Empty DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame()

# api header
headers = {"Accept": "application/json","Authorization": "api_secret"}

#email for loops
email_list = ["abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com"]

#supposed to read 2 emails in the list and append each df but only reads the first one...# 

for i in email_list:

  querystring = {"where":i}  
  response = requests.request("GET", "https://example.com/api/2.0/export", headers=headers, params=querystring) 

  with open('test.jsonl', 'w') as writefile:
    writefile.write(response.text)    
  data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('test.jsonl', 'r')]
  FIELDS = ["event"]
  df = pd.json_normalize(data)[FIELDS]
  df = df.append(df)
```

I wonder if I need to change something in df append but I can't pinpoint where needs to be changed. thank you so much in advance!

Comment: start by fixing your indentation, please, as it is it can't run

Comment: did you check that: a/ your file contains the expected content b/ your `data` array contains the expected content?

Comment: what do you think this does `df = pd.json_normalize(data)[FIELDS]
df = df.append(df)`? Especially the second line?

Comment: hi @njzk2! so sorry but I'm really new with python. 1) can you point out what portion is wrong with indentation? As for 3) my intention was to pick the specific field in [FIELDS] and make a dataframe and keep appending it using df.append in the for loop. 2) yes there is contents! but it's not appending even though i see two specific json outputs.

Comment: Just make sure the indentation here matches what you are running. Also `df = pd.json_normalize(data)[FIELDS]` creates a new dataframe. then `df = df.append(df)` appends it to itself.

Comment: oh my that was it!! that's why I was only seeing 1 dataframe. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)[FIELDS]
df = df.append(df)
```

overwrites the dataframe each time instead, create a new one before appending:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data)[FIELDS]
df = df.append(df2)
```